# Redirecting to a custom forgot password page

Tags: php, password, reset

I have created a custom login and registration page with the plugin 'User Registration' and they both work perfectly fine, however, on the login page if I click on the ‘Forgot password’ link, it takes me to the default WordPress password reset page. Is there any way to redirect to a custom page that I have created for this purpose?

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,
Nora

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change/rewrite the lost password url?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161908/how-to-change-rewrite-the-lost-password-url)

Comment: Please share the plugin link.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, there's a hook to change the lost password URL.

I found it by going to this nice page to search all the hooks and filters and selecting 'Hooks' and trying 'lost password' https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/

An example from here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/lostpassword_url

```
    add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'my_lost_password_page', 10, 2 );

    function my_lost_password_page( $lostpassword_url, $redirect ) {
        return home_url( "/yournew/lostpasswordpage.php" );
    }
```