# How to customize the Lost Password URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, password

I have a WordPress website on which I have changed the default login url from “mydomain.com/wp-login.php” to “mydomain.com/login”.
Currently my lost password URL is at “mydomain.com/login?action=’lostpassword'”. How can I change the URL in order to have it at “mydomain.com/lostpassword”?

I changed the link using the lostpassword_url filter, but now I have to somehow display the default lost password page on the new custom link (it is currently showing "Page not found").

I am not trying to display a custom lost password page, but to display the default lost password page on a custom url.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Keep in mind that `wp-login.php` isn't a permalink but a direct file URL, the WP rewrite rule system won't apply. Changing the URL WP thinks it's at won't be enough either as it'll just lead to a 404 if the original isn't somehow mapped or moved. If it's a redirect you're after though, then that becomes ***signifiicantly easier*** to answer. Otherwise it may be impossible without bulding a custom page that's a replica

Comment: @TomJNowell I am trying to spoof the Lost Password Page URL in order to not disclose the page where the admin login is located.
The idea behind it is that for the website there are two Login pages (one for the users and one for the admins), therefore if the users want to change their passwords I do not want to disclose the admin page. 
What would be the best solution for this problem?

Comment: So you have a custom login for users, and the admins use the standard WP login? Or have I misunderstood? keep in mind that WP already has nuilt in rewrite rules shortcuts for login and admin at `/login` and `/admin` that redirect to the appropriate places. This also won't improve security

Comment: Yes, I have a custom login for users and the admins use the standard WP Login.
The /login and /admin are already disabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change/rewrite the lost password url?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161908/how-to-change-rewrite-the-lost-password-url)